# Smooth scroll function prevents the image filter function

Tags: javascript

Thanks for every one who helped me so far. There is another problem related to JS. Can anyone with advance knowledge, help me to fix this error? My website has both smooth scroll effect and, image filter with JavaScript. But smooth scroll function prevents the functionality of image filter function. I cannot upload complete html css and JavaScript codes because this website prevents it. So I will upload the JavaScript code. Please look at this and help me to fix it.

```js
// ISOTOPE PORTFOLIO WITH FILTER
  if(isExists('.portfolioContainer')){
   var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
   $container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
     duration: 750,
     easing: 'linear',
     queue: false
    }
   });
   
   $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function(){
    $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
   
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
     filter: selector,
     animationOptions: {
      duration: 750,
      easing: 'linear',
      queue: false
     }
     });
     return false;
   }); 
  }
    
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "#portfolio") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 400, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to following?

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 400
}, function(){
    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
});
```

I have added the queue:false option to your last animate function. This is enabled by default.

*Update:*
Can you check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peterbode1989/08c4q7L1/)? I'm currently trying to re-create your working situation. Does the fiddle looks like your working environment?
What I already found out is, that `$("a").on('click', fun...` is also called / triggered when pressing a isotop filter button.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it.But image filter  still doesn't work. Please help me